# Find all possible multiplications numbers to a specified sum. C#

Tags: c#

I need help with finding all possible unordered representations for a given natural number n(breakdowns) of n as a product of natural numbers (not necessarily different).
An integer n is entered from the keyboard.

**Example: input: 50 output: 25 * 2 , 10 * 5 , 5 * 5 * 2**

Hint: The algorithm by which you can perform the decomposition is analogous to the one that is
described in problem 3. Instead of devNum (n-k, cnt + 1) we will recursively call devNum (n / k, cnt + 1), when
this is not for every k, but only for those for which n% k == 0. The condition for continuing
the break (loop for) will be k & gt; 1, not k ≥ 1, i.e. the bottom of the recursion will be k == 1, not
k == 0 (the latter is easily explained: 0 and 1 are precisely the identities of the operations of addition and
multiplication).

Comment: You have the answer in your question, so what do you need help with? How did you do problem 3?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This program I wrote may be close to what you're looking for. It would be helpful if you provided more information to the problem and any answers to prior questions (like question #3) and/or examples or clues provided by the homework on how the program is modeled. I can see there are strict constraints on how to write it, and not all of those exact boundaries are followed here. However, recursion is used on the same function with the same parameters, with similar arguments passed under certain conditionals. A list of lists is used to store the different sets of factors/divisors.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a positive integer: ");
        int n;
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a whole number."); 
        }
        List<List<int>> factors = FindFactors(n);
        PrintFactors(factors);
    }

    public static List<List<int>> FindFactors(int n)
    {
        var res = new List<List<int>>();
        if (n > 0) {
            for (var i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                var temp = devNum(n, i);
                foreach (var list in temp)
                {
                    list.Reverse();
                    if (list.Count > 2 && list[list.Count - 1] == 1)
                    {
                        list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);
                    }
                    res.Add(list);
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    private static List<List<int>> devNum(int n, int k)
    {
        var beginWithFirst = new List<List<int>>();
        if (n % k != 0 || (n > 1 && k == 1))
        {
            return beginWithFirst;
        }

        if (k == 1)
        {
            var end = new List<int>();
            end.Add(k);
            beginWithFirst.Add(end);
            return beginWithFirst;
        }

        for (var i = n / k; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            var temp = devNum(n / k, i);
            foreach (var list in temp.Where(list => list.Count > 0 && list[list.Count - 1] <= k))
            {
                list.Add(k);
                beginWithFirst.Add(list);
            }
        }

        return beginWithFirst;
    }
    
    public static void PrintFactors(List<List<int>> factors) {
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (List<int> lst in factors) {
            counter++;
            int[] arr = lst.ToArray();
            if (counter != factors.Count) {
                Console.Write("{0}", string.Join(" * ", arr) + ", ");
            }
            else {
                Console.Write("{0}", string.Join(" * ", arr));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[DotNet Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IzarxH)